# hasNextLine() does basically nothing

Tags: java

I want to write a code to reverse every word in a line character by character,as the following:

```
Input = Life is good 
Output = efiL si doog
```

I was able to do that by using 2 scanners(This works perfectly):

```
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(text); //this was used in the code before, so i am emptying the memory
      String result = "";
      scan.nextLine();
      String text = scan.nextLine();
      Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(text);
      while(scan2.hasNext()) 
      {
        String text2 = scan2.next(); 
        result = result + " " + reverse(text2); 
      }      
      System.out.println("Reverse version : " + result);
```

But while i was trying to achieve this by one scanner, something very distracting happened:

```
          Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in); 
          String result = "";
          scan2.nextLine();
          String text = scan2.nextLine();
          while(scan2.hasNext()) 
          {
            text = scan2.next(); 
            result = result + " " + reverse(text); 
          }      
          System.out.println("Reverse version : " + result);
```

Actually, the main problem is that: Changing this code as `scan2.hasNext()` or `!scan2.hasNext()` outputs no visible result at all. 'While' still initiates and goes into an infinite loop in both cases. Not taking any input for text before the loop also initiates the it. I know that i can exit by Ctrl + D, but as you can see i don't want to do that.

The second code may have mistakes since it is changed a lot, but the main problem remains.

A begginner is here, so every explanation will be helpful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you tried CTRL+Z?

Comment: I know it can be used, but since this is a part of another code,i want it to be used smoothly, not by commands. Also, the first code is able to do the trick without any keyboard command.

Comment: try removing `scan` and using code with `scan2` only from first solution

Comment: Out of interest, why are you calling `scan2.nextLine()` twice consecutively in the second snippet?

Comment: @yiabiten can't, since second scanner just reads "text" part.

Comment: @JonK just to be sure, actually, that the memory is clean.

Comment: @Deligoz You're calling `scan2.nextLine()` and ignoring the entered value twice, just to be sure that the memory is clear for `scan2.next()`?

Answer (score 2):

You're reading from `System.in`. `System.in` is where the user enters text, and the text is only readable once you press Enter.

The Scanner has no way to know if you will continue typing text or not. So it can only return when it knows that there is a next token (because you typed something and pressed Enter), or when it knows there is no next token (because you closed the stream by typing Ctrl-D). So, if you don't type anything, it blocks, waiting for your input.

It's unclear what you want to achieve. The only way for the scanner to stop blocking is to close the stream by pressing Ctrl-D, or to enter a specific word, check that word in the code, and break out of the loop if the word has been entered.

I also don't understand why you read two lines and ignore them before entering the loop.

Comment: I see, so it is an impossible task. My goal was (sorry, i can see it isn't clear as i read it again) printing reverse version without giving an end command, just by pressing enter. I thought that scan.hasNext() might do the trick, but it looks like it doesn't. Thank you for answer. edit: the reason of two lines was, first to clean the memory if not and second to initiate the loop by filling the memory. I know it looks silly, and it is, i corrupted the code a bit when trying to change it and that is the result :)

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result;
        String text;

        while (true) {
            text = scan.nextLine();
            result = new StringBuffer(text).reverse().toString();
            System.out.println("Reverse version : " + result);
        }
    }
}
```